# Android - использование Plurals в отношении секунд, минут, часов, дней

Tags: android, строки

Приветствую!
Подскажите как правильнее использовать Plurals в отношении секунд, минут, часов, дней для вывода времени которое "осталось" и "прошло"

```
<plurals name="second_plurals">
        <item quantity="zero">секунд</item>
        <item quantity="one">%1$d секунда</item>
        <item quantity="few">%1$d секунды</item>
        <item quantity="many">%1$d секунд</item>
        <item quantity="other">%1$d секунд</item>
</plurals>
```

zero, one, two - понятно, но к примеру few - это насколько я понимаю от 2х до 5, а 5 уже будет не "секунды" и "секунд". И далее - с many, например 101 секунда, 102 секунды,... т.е. действовать должны правила для one, two.
Как учесть эту разницу?

Comment: Держите, на мой взгляд полная и одновременно краткая статья о plurals     http://www.dimasokol.ru/plurals-in-android/

Comment: Может дешевле будет сократить до «сек.» и не париться?

Comment: metalurgus, осваивал именно по этой статье. Вопрос остался незакрытым

Comment: @Ruben, значит плохо осваивали, там есть ответы на все ваши вопросы. Нужно только прочитать не через слово, а полностью

Answer (score 28):

[Статья](http://www.dimasokol.ru/plurals-in-android/)

> zero — строка для нуля, отсутствия чего-либо; в некоторых языках — ещё
>   и для чисел, оканчивающихся нулём; one —  строка для чисел,
>   заканчивающихся на единицу; в некоторых языках — только для единицы;
>
> two — для чисел, заканчивающихся на двойку, или только для двойки;
>
> few— здесь, под словом «несколько», уже не скрывается конкретики,
>   обработка полностью зависит от языковых правил; например, для русского
>   языка это относится к числам, оканчивающимся на 2, 3 и 4 (именно так,
>   несмотря на наличие правила «two»);
>
> many — аналогично, «неконкретная»
>   категория, можно понимать её как «нечто побольше few»; в русском языке
>   — от пятёрки и выше;
>
> other — всё остальное.

Если кратко, то уникальные правила сформулированы для каждого языка в отдельности.
В конце статьи есть пример, который должен развеють все недопонимания:

```
<plurals name="plurals_2">
    <item quantity="zero">нет андроидов</item>
    <item quantity="one">%1$d андроид</item>
    <item quantity="two">%1$d андроида</item>
    <item quantity="few">%1$d андроида</item>
    <item quantity="many">%1$d андроидов</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d андроидов</item>
</plurals>



// Выведем данные в формате: 8 = many : 8 андроидов
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    String pluralTest = this.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.plurals_1, i, i);
    String pluralAndroid = this.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.plurals_2, i, i);
    android.util.Log.i("Plurals", pluralTest + " : " + pluralAndroid);
}
```

Результат:

```
0 = many : 0 андроидов
1 = one : 1 андроид
2 = few : 2 андроида
3 = few : 3 андроида
4 = few : 4 андроида
5 = many : 5 андроидов
6 = many : 6 андроидов
7 = many : 7 андроидов
8 = many : 8 андроидов
9 = many : 9 андроидов
10 = many : 10 андроидов
11 = many : 11 андроидов
12 = many : 12 андроидов
13 = many : 13 андроидов
14 = many : 14 андроидов
15 = many : 15 андроидов
16 = many : 16 андроидов
17 = many : 17 андроидов
18 = many : 18 андроидов
19 = many : 19 андроидов
20 = many : 20 андроидов
21 = one : 21 андроид
22 = few : 22 андроида
23 = few : 23 андроида
24 = few : 24 андроида
25 = many : 25 андроидов
26 = many : 26 андроидов
27 = many : 27 андроидов
28 = many : 28 андроидов
29 = many : 29 андроидов
```

Итого, для русского языка:
Для нуля используется **zero**
Для чисел, заканчивающихся на 1(кроме чисел, заканчивающихся на *11*) используется **one**
Для чисел, заканчивающихся на 2(кроме чисел, заканчивающихся на *12*) используется **two** (вот только в русском для этих чисел используется правило **few**)
Для чисел, заканчивающихся на 3, 4 (кроме чисел, заканчивающихся на *13*, *14*) используется **few**
Для всех остальных используется **many**
**other** используется для других случаев, которых в русском языке нет.
Несмотря на это, **one** и **other** - обязательный минимум, который должен всегда быть определен.

В этой же статье описана проблема с plurals на API < 3.0. Там все plurals работают по правилам английского языка. Там же описано и решение этой проблемы - использовать библиотеку [android-i18n-plurals,](https://code.google.com/p/android-i18n-plurals/)

П. С. Все вышеописанное я взял из вышеперведенной статьи, и если

> осваивал именно по этой статье. Вопрос остался незакрытым

то это означает только одно - плохо осваивал.

Comment: Это работает для устройств с русской локалью, так что не забудьте написать свою функцию для общего случая.

Answer (score 4):

Для русского языка one - это все числа, заканчивающиеся на 1, кроме 11. few - заканчивющиеся на 2 - 4, кроме 12 - 14. То есть проблем не будет.

Для форматирования относительных дат, чтобы самому не возиться, можно воспользоваться [DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29) и другими методами этого класса. Так у вас будет текст не только для одного языка.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решилась... забыл переименовать values в values-ru, а то у меня практически все числа попадали в OTHER. Всем спасибо, проблема решена

Answer (score 0):

Немного "покапитаню" если в вашей android ОС выбран Английский язык, то приложение будет искать папку values-en, если она не найдена, то будут браться ресурсы из папки values. Аналогично и для Русского языка, если язык ОС выбран русский, то ресурсы сначала будут искаться в values-ru, и если таковой не существует то возьмутся из values.

Менять язык ОС - **Настройки - Язык и ввод**

Для полного понимания вопроса, нужно почитать про локализацию приложений.
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php

Comment: Использую эмулятор с английским интерфейсом (по умолчанию). strings.xml только один. Берутся неверные значения (other почти для всех случаев).

Answer (score 0):

Если на телефоне стоит английский язык - то при использовании plurals значение для кейса 2 будет заменено значением  для zero. Это потому что в английском грамматическая форма для 0 и много одинаковая. И если это использовать в приложении где язык русский - то будет 2 Билетов а не 2 Билета