# Есть некоий метод немогу понять его суть

Tags: java, android, httpbackend

Использую бэкэнд в бэкэнлдлесс. У адаптера `ListView` есть `View` метод, отвечающий за вставку текста в поле

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        View view = convertView == null ? mInflater.inflate( mResource, parent, false ) : convertView;

        TextView restaurantNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.restaurantName );
        TextView cuisineView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.restaurantCuisine );
        TextView locationsNumberView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.restaurantLocations );

        Restaurant item = getItem( position );

        restaurantNameView.setText( item.getName() );
        cuisineView.setText( item.getCuisine() );
        String locationsNumberTextTemplate = getContext().getResources().getQuantityString( R.plurals.restaurant_locations, item.getLocations().size() );
        locationsNumberView.setText( String.format( locationsNumberTextTemplate, item.getLocations().size() ) );

        return view;
    }
```

из этого кода не могу понять  вот эти строки вы бы мне очень помогли

```
 String locationsNumberTextTemplate = getContext().getResources().getQuantityString( R.plurals.restaurant_locations, item.getLocations().size() );
    locationsNumberView.setText( String.format( locationsNumberTextTemplate, item.getLocations().size() ) );
```

если сказали для чего он и с какой целью

Comment: в этой строке производится [склонение по числительным](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430662/177345) (1 стол, 2 стола и тд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, существует ли в классе (или в интерфейсе класса) с этим методом метод getContext()

Comment: я понел о чем вы  locationsNumberView.setText( String.format( locationsNumberTextTemplate, item.getLocations().size() ) );

Comment: он передеает номер из бд

Comment: String locationsNumberTextTemplate = getContext().getResources().getQuantityString( R.plurals.restaurant_locations, item.getLocations().size() )

Comment: вот собственно зачем этот метод что он делает????

Comment: он получает номер из бд*

Comment: В данном случае мы получаем значение из getContext().getResources() и склоняем getQuantityString() (мн. ч или ед. ч). После всего записываем в поле TextView locationsNumberView которое мы получаем выше найдя его по ID.

Comment: locationsNumberView - это ссылка на объект

Comment: Хотя могу ошибаться, тесно с java не связывался

Comment: Например 1 город, 2 города, 6 городов

Comment: [документация android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)