# java - Метод для генерации постфикса к возрасту (год/года/лет)

Tags: java

```
String generate(int age) {
   int age = list.get(position).getAge();
   int lastChar = Integer.parseInt((""+age).substring((""+age).length()-1, (""+age).length()));
   String old = "";
   if (age==11) old = "лет";
   else if((""+age).endsWith("1")) old = "год";
   else if(age>11 && age<15) old = "лет";
   else if(lastChar>1 && lastChar<5) old = "года";
   else old = "лет";
   return old;
}
```

Все работает, но мне кажется, что он довольно большой. Слишком большой. Юзаю его везде где это требуется, но только сейчас задумался - может все проще, чем кажется? Мне кажется это велосипед

Comment: В принципе что-то есть.... только проще манипулировать всегда через  `lastChar` наверное.

Comment: Неужели в `java` нет чего-то вспомогающего, что поможет? Класс `Math` может быть.

Comment: `if (lastChar == 1)
            old = "год";
        else if(lastChar == 0 || lastChar >= 5 && lastChar <= 9)
            old = "лет";
        else if(lastChar >= 2 && lastChar <= 4)
            old = "года";
        else
            old = "что-то еще";` ........ а что в `Math` такого должно содержаться?.... в принципе это примерно общие принципы итернационализации..на сколько помнится `0; с 1 на конце; от 2 до 4 на конце; от 5 до 9 и ноль тоже может быть тут; прочие` .....

Comment: Сделайте ответом :)

Comment: Эта задача решается вообще иначе через плюралы. Правда я не знаю как это на чистой яве, но вот в андроиде это решается вообще просто http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430528/android-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-plurals-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9/430662#430662

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тут скорее вопрос стоит в том, это нужно для единственной функции или всё же планируется интернационализация программы/приложения. Если мультиязык планируется, то и в java в принципе, по-другому можно делать. Заготавливать шаблоны свои и пользоваться некоторыми другими функциями

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Во-первых, чтобы получить последнюю цифру от числа, достаточно взять остаток от деления на 10.

   ```
   int ageLastNumber = age % 10;
   ```
2. Далее манипулировать уже только им. Т.к., в теории, общие принципы интернационализации такие:

   - 0;
   - с 1 на конце; (21, 31, 41 и т.д.)
   - от 2 до 4 на конце; (2, 4, 22, 24 и т.д.)
   - от 5 до 9 и ноль тоже может быть тут; (25-30, 35-40 и т.д.)
   - исключение 11-14 (считаются как 5-9)
   - прочие

   то получим

   ```
   String old = "";
   boolean isExclusion = (age % 100 >= 11) && (age % 100 <= 14);

   if (ageLastNumber == 1)
       old = "год";
   else if(ageLastNumber == 0 || ageLastNumber >= 5 && ageLastNumber <= 9)
       old = "лет";
   else if(ageLastNumber >= 2 && ageLastNumber <= 4)
       old = "года";
   if (isExclusion)
       old = "лет";
   ```

Можно что-то отдельно выделить для себя. Например в [php](/questions/tagged/php) у фреймворка [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) есть вот [такая система](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/tutorial-i18n.md#%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE):

```
=0 означает ноль;
=1 соответствует ровно 1;
one - 21, 31, 41 и так далее;
few - от 2 до 4, от 22 до 24 и так далее;
many - 0, от 5 до 20, от 25 до 30 и так далее;
other - для всех прочих чисел (например, дробных).
```

---

Итого, грубо говоря, на данный момент, получается так:

```
int age = 5;
int ageLastNumber = age % 10;
boolean exclusion = (age % 100 >= 11) && (age % 100 <= 14);
String old = "";

if (ageLastNumber == 1)
    old = "год";
else if(ageLastNumber == 0 || ageLastNumber >= 5 && ageLastNumber <= 9)
    old = "лет";
else if(ageLastNumber >= 2 && ageLastNumber <= 4)
    old = "года";
if (isExclusion)
        old = "лет";

System.out.println(old);
```

Comment: Блестяще! Спасибо :)

Comment: У итогового кода в этом ответе много недостатков. Во-первых, использование нестандартного механизма интернационализации вместо ChoiceFormat - в реальном коде эта логика потребует дополнительного покрытия тестами. Во-вторых, плохой выбор имен переменных - имя lastChar никак не соответствует типу int. В-третьих, здесь есть чисто логическая ошибка - ветвь "что-то еще" недостижима и это является хорошим признаком того, что код можно упростить.

Comment: @IvanGammel как я писал в комментарии под вопросом `вопрос стоит в том, это нужно для единственной функции или всё же планируется интернационализация программы/приложения`........... то есть если это единственно, что планируется, то смысл от `ChoiceFormat` - нулевой.......`lastChar` взята из кода автора, чтоб ему было легче ориентироваться, навигация более понятна. С `else` да, можно удалить............ В принципе последние два момента поправил. чтоб зануды не занудствовали ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поправьте еще для случаев 12-14 лет.

Comment: @СергейГрушин для 11-14 лет добавил условие еще. Возможно можно немного оптимизировать.

Answer (score 2):

Более уместным, чем реализация логики вручную на if-ах, будет использование класса `ChoiceFormat` из стандартной библиотеки.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html

Пример кода для вашего случая:

```
public static StringBuilder appendAge(StringBuilder, int age) {
   assert age > 0 : "Age must be a positive number";
   double[] limits = {0, 1, 2, 5};
   String[] strings = {"лет", "год", "года", "лет"};
   ChoiceFormat format = new ChoiceFormat(limits, strings);
   int rule = 11 <= (age % 100) && (age % 100) <= 14 ? age : age % 10;
   return builder.append(age).append(' ').append(format.format(rule));
}
```

Более сложные примеры описаны в этой статье Java Tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html

Comment: ваш пример точно будет правильно работать для "12 лет" ?

Comment: @4per, конечно, нет, вы правы. Поправил код.

Comment: Не ожидал) Но первый ответ мне больше нравится))

Comment: Можно узнать в чем это будет уместнее для одного единственного случая перевода?

Comment: Лучше не изобретать велосипед там, где это возможно. Ещё лучше было бы взять icu4j вместо ChoiceFormat, потому что эта библиотека лучше описывает правила.

Comment: @IvanGammel изобретение велосипеда, как минимум, дает работу мозгу, хотя бы мизерную.. И без изобретений велосипедов не было бы различных фреймворков, библиотек, плагинов, операционных систем, собственно, самих различных видов велосипедов и прочего. Поэтому с этим можно поспорить вполне. Тем более на уровне маленькой задачки это вполне уместно. Не зря на вопрос "как отсортировать массив?" дадут не один и не два и не три способа это сделать. Потому что это велосипеды, имеющие место быть.

Comment: Все зависит от целей разработчика. Если цель - научиться, то велосипеды надо и изобретать самому, и исследовать чужие. Если цель - сделать продукт, который должен работать и поддерживаться, то оправданность любого велосипеда измеряется суммой, которую он может сэкономить в сравнении с существующим решением. В большинстве случаев (особенно в таких, как сортировка) эта сумма отрицательна.

Comment: @IvanGammel вот видите, вы и согласились что они оправданы в некоторых моментах. Поэтому неоправданное абсолютное утверждение `Более уместным, чем реализация логики вручную на if-ах, будет .....` - никак не является верным. И, т.к. вы не знаете что сейчас делает автор, утверждать это, в принципе, как-то глупо %) ..... `оправданность любого велосипеда измеряется суммой, которую он может сэкономить в сравнении с существующим решением` - проблема в том, что нужно знать что они существуют или много долго искать перед тем как найти, а решение с ифами накидывается за 5 минут. плюс минус.

Comment: @IvanGammel Это я всё к чему. Вы утверждаете, практически абсолютно, что "вот это верно и точка", но при этом говорите, что надо узнать ситуацию и действовать по обстоятельствам, сами это не выяснив и отсеять то, что может иметь альтернативу :-P