# Генерация формы множественного числа

Tags: php, массивы, числа, множества, nlp

Здравствуй, дали задачу по PHP

Напишите массив с числами от 1 до 30
[1, 2, 3 ....]
и функцию, которая делает следующее
проходит по массиву и каждому числу дописывает фразу  "новых комментариев" и эти слова склоняются в соответствии с их числом
и делает в итоге массив
1 новый комментарий
2 новых комментария
и тд
и вывести на экран в 
html в элементе

***Прошу помочь с примерами решения***, в PHP я новичок, теорию изучил не плохо но сижу несколько дней и не дошло пока что использовать в этом примере.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599065/191482  метод решения

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть [статья](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html?id=l10n/pluralforms) относительно множественных чисел. Там собраны алгоримы определения множественного числа для многих стран. Алгоритмы представлены в виде формул. Не нужно изобретать велосипед. Мы же используем формулы в математике.

В данном случае мы берем русский язык: `nplurals=3`
То есть для русского языка три множественные формы: 
**1)** Когда элемент один. ***Например***: 1 новый комментарий 
**2)** Когда элементов больше двух, но меньше пяти. ***Например***: 3 комментария, 4 комментария
**3)** Когда элементов больше или равно пяти. ***Например***: 5 новых комментариев, 6 новых комменариев

Теперь перейдем к реализации. Условия привел в более читаемый вид:

```
$numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

function plural($number)
{
    if ($number % 10 == 1 && $number % 100 != 11) {
        return $number . ' новый комментарий';
    } else {
        if ($number % 10 >= 2 && $number % 10 <= 4 && ($number % 100 < 10 || $number % 100 >= 20)) {
            return ($number . ' новых комментария');
        } else {
            return ($number . ' новых комментариев');
        }
    }
}

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo plural($number);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: статья интересная, просто по таблице прошёлся и для любой страны взял формулу. Очень удобно, взял тоже на заметку, спасибо

Comment: Можно даже написать класс для удобства, собрав формулы под все страны. При мультиязычности понадобиться в будущем. Рад, что помог

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд самое элегантное решение функции `plural` такое:

```
function plural($number, $array){
   $keys = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
   return $array[$number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20 ? 2 : $keys[min($number % 10, 5)]];
}
```

Как это работает:

Есть массив со склонениями

```
$array[' новый комментарий', ' новых комментария', ' новых комментариев']
```

Cоставляем массив ключей  `$keys = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];`

- `$keys[0] = 2;` → `$array[2]` = 'новых комментариев' → 0, 20, 30, 10020... 'новых комментариев'
- `$keys[1] = 0;` → `$array[0]` = 'новый комментарий' → 1, 21, 31... 'новый комментарий'
- `$keys[2] = $keys[3] = $keys[4] = 1;` → `$array[1]` = 'новых комментария' → 2, 3, 4, 31, 32, 33, 34 ... 'новых комментария'
- `$keys[5] = 2;` → после 5-х всегда 'новых комментариев' → 5 'новых комментариев', 1006 'новых комментариев'

Поэтому `$array[$keys[min($number%10, 5)]];`

На этом бы можно было закончить, **НО**...есть 11, 12, 13 'новый комментарий' — это исключение. Запишем `$number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20 ? 2`

Итак, разобрались  с выражением `$number%100 > 4 && $number%100 < 20 ? 2`: что если остаток отделения в пределах 4–20, то всегда - новых комментариев.

Теперь составляем массив с элементами массива, а потом просто в цикле обходим весь массив и конкатенируем его значение.

```
$arrays = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

foreach($arrays as $key=>$val) {
   $arrays[$key] .= plural($val, array(' новый комментарий', ' новых комментария', ' новых комментариев'));
}

var_dump($arrays);
```

**Обновлено**

*Почему такой порядок ключей?* `$keys = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];`

Есть массив ключей `$keys = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];` и массив склонений `$array[' новый комментарий', ' новых комментария', ' новых комментариев']`.
Для простоты  рассмотрим значения от `0- 10`:

0 - `$keys[0] = 2, а $array[2] = "..ев";`
1 - `$keys[1] = 0, а $array[0]  = "..й";`
2 - `$keys[2] = 1, а $array[1]  = "..я";`
3 - `$keys[3] = 1, а $array[1] = "..я";`
4 - `$keys[4] = 1, а $array[1] = "..я";`

а всё что после пяти это будет "...ев";

5,6,7,8,9 - `$keys[5] = 2 $array[2] "..ев";`
По такому принципу можно склоняются все числа **кроме** 11,12,13,14

Comment: => Алексей Шиманский.А зачем Вы используете именно такой порядок ключей?

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade причём тут я?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не обратил внимание на автора. С мобильного сидел. Прошу прощения. Тогда вопрос к автору

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade есть массив ключей  `$keys = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];` и массив склонений `$array[' новый комментарий', ' новых комментария', ' новых комментариев']`. Рассмотрим значения от 0- 10

Comment: 0 - `$keys[0] = 2`  `$array[2]` "..ев";  
1 - `$keys[1] = 0`  `$array[0]` "..й";  
2 - `$keys[2] = 1`  `$array[1]` "..я";  
3 - `$keys[3] = 1`  `$array[1]` "..я";  
4 - `$keys[4] = 1`  `$array[1]` "..я";  
а всё что после пяти это "ев";    
5 - `$keys[5] = 2`  `$array[2]` "..ев";

Comment: И так все числа, кроме 11,12,13,14 - там будет "..ев"