# Пользователь вводит возраст в виде "22" а получает ответ в виде "Тебе 22 года"

Tags: javascript

Подскажите почему не работает

```
        <form>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="Years">
        </p>
        <p>                         
            <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="howOld(form)">
        </p>
        </form>
        <body>
            <script>
            function howOld(form){
                var yserOld = form.Years.value;
                if(yserOld % 10 >= 5 && yserOld % 10 <= 9 || yserOld % 10 == 0)
                    alert('Тебе 'yersOld + ' лет.');
                else
                    alert('Тебе 'yersOld + ' года.');
                }       
            </script>
```

Comment: Так `form` еще получить у документа надо перед передачей в функцию...

Comment: @Mbmenes   По крайней мере тег <form> должен быть внутри тега <body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что очень много опечаток.

```js
function howOld(form) {
  var yearsOld = form.Years.value;
  if (yearsOld % 10 >= 5 && yearsOld % 10 <= 9 || yearsOld % 10 == 0)
    alert('Тебе ' + yearsOld + ' лет.');
  else
    alert('Тебе ' + yearsOld + ' года.');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="Years">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="howOld(form)">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "Тебе 12 года." доставляет :)

Comment: Спасибо. Прошу прощение за не внимательность, впредь буду аккуратней.

Comment: Младенцам до 2-х лет незаходить:) (это неважно, просто посчитал - удивился)

Comment: if (yearsOld <1) alert ('Младенец')

Comment: @Mbmenes, если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его решением, поставив галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: 21, 31, 41, 51 и т.д. - "год"  ...... можете алгоритм генерации множественного числа посмотреть тут : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646949/191482

Answer (score 2):

Просто в качестве "поделиться":

```js
/**
 * @param integer num - number of entities
 * @param array variants - [nominative,  genitive, plural]
 * @param string locale - localization, only 'ru' implemented
 */
function pluralize(f, variants, locale) {
  const NOMINATIVE = 0;
  const GENITIVE = 1;
  const PLURAL = 2;
  let num = Math.floor(f);
  let dec = num % 10;
  switch (locale) {
    default:
    case 'ru':
      num %= 100;
      if (11 <= num && num <= 19) return variants[PLURAL];
      if (f > 0 && f < 1) return variants[GENITIVE];
      if (f > 1 && f < 2) return variants[GENITIVE];
      if (dec == 1) return variants[NOMINATIVE];
      if (~[2, 3, 4].indexOf(dec)) return variants[GENITIVE];
      return variants[PLURAL];
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 23; i += 0.5) {
  console.log(i, pluralize(i, ['год', 'года', 'лет']))
}
```

Comment: И как ваш ответ связан с вопросом о проблемах с обработкой формы?

Comment: Я написал, что это просто share.. Поставили минус, идите дальше, я не в курсе какого ответа вы ждёте.

Comment: Или вы находите, что у автора всё в порядке с алгоритмом и этот ответ ничем ему не поможет?

Comment: Ваш ответ ему ничем не поможет. Потому, что у автора проблема с формой, а не с множественным числом. И да, ru.SO - это про вопрос-ответ. Про "_просто share_" - это не сюда.