# "Time Since/Ago" metod. android studio, java

Tags: java, android-studio

Кто знает, как написать метод, который будет высчитывать сколько времени назад пользователь сделал то, или иное действие, и будет возвращать ответ в виде "1 минуту назад", "5 минут назад", "1 час назад"? Время приходит в формате Unix, и  его получается нужно пропустить через этот метод.

Comment: Для решения вам точно понадобятся ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430528/177345), хотя он и не полностью отвечает на ваш.

Comment: что выводит это уже второй вопрос. Сейчас необходима логика. Но за подсказку спасибо.